# Any researchers doing research in Nietzschean psychology?

Tags: unconscious, psychoanalysis, moral-psychology, religion, freud

I am eager to do research in **Nietzschean psychology**
Are there any researchers doing research in this area?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I am lead to believe, Nietzsche was more a philosopher than a psychologist but he did come up with theories which are in the realm of psychology. I don't know that there are many Nitzschean researchers within Psychology but https://doi.org/10.1159/000510971 may help.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris!